# IOS Firebase query access by value

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how can i get given json object by value using query. In details, want to get [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W020.png) for id:4 without looping all events in the json table

[image]

Comment: Which language are you using exactly? Obj-C or Swift? Your tags are a bit confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 2**

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("events").queryOrderedByChild("id").queryEqualToValue(4).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(Snap) in 
  if let snapDict = Snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
      for each in snapDict{
          print(each.0) // Will print out your node ID = 1
          print(each.1) //Will print out your Dictionary inside that node.
          }

      }

  })
```

**Swift 3**

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("events").queryOrdered(byChild: "id").queryEqual(toValue: 4).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snap) in
        if let snapDict = Snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
            for each in snapDict{
                print(each.0) // Will print out your node ID = 1
                print(each.1) //Will print out your Dictionary inside that node.
            }

        }

    })
```

Comment: Accept this as answer if it solved your issue :) Happy Coding

Comment: what a quiet code. It helped me really.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Might be solve your problem

```
[self.dbRef observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    if (![snapshot.value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        NSArray *arrResponse = (NSArray *)snapshot.value;

        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id = %@", serchID];
        NSArray *arrSearchedVal = [arrResponse filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    }
}];
```

**NB:** dbRef is your FIRDatabaseReference, which returns the whole data JSON. Then use NSPredicate with your search id and you will get your result.

[image]

[image]

Happy coding ..